# C++ Generic templated functors

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I've to do a templated functor which can be used as :

```
Function<int (char)> f = &printChar;
Function<int (char)> f = boost::bind(&printChar, _1);
```

I did a functor based on a function pointer but it doesn't work with boost::bind because it returns a boost::Function which is an object and not a function ptr.

```
class Function <R()> {
public:
    typedef R (*ptr_t)();
    ptr_t _ptr;

    Function(ptr_t p) { _ptr = p; }
    R operator()() { return _ptr(); }
}
```

How could I handle an object in a generic way ?

Thx

Comment: `boost::bind` does **not** return a `boost::function`

Comment: After few tests i actually could use the return of boost::bind as a function, so i don't understand... what it returned ?

Comment: Whatever `boost::bind` returns is an object that's callable, its actual type is unspecified and is an implementation detail. `boost::function` will hold anything, be it pointer or object, as long as its callable with the signature given. Now if you are looking to write your own `boost::function`, you could start by looking at the implementation of `boost::function` itself...